# GMSPlacePicker pickPlace method crash in simulator swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I have a problem with Place Picker in my simulator. it is crashing with

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c15dd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bbbf21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c07415f -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 351
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c073fcb +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59
    4   myApp                              0x0000000106f64c58 -[GMSPlatformKeyInsertingPlacesServerClient setPlacesService:] + 376
    5   myApp                              0x0000000106f64ac6 -[GMSPlatformKeyInsertingPlacesServerClient placesService] + 104
    6   myApp                              0x0000000106f64163 -[GMSPlatformKeyInsertingPlacesServerClient executeQuery:completionHandler:] + 88
    7   myApp                              0x0000000106f639f3 -[GMSPlacesServerClient accountPlacePickerSessionWithRequestSource:callback:] + 343
    8   myApp                              0x0000000106f88d60 -[GMSPlacesClient accountPlacePickerSessionWithCallback:] + 147
    9   myApp                              0x0000000106f58564 -[GMSPlacePicker pickPlaceWithResultCallback:didDisappearCallback:] + 887
    10  myApp                              0x0000000106b12273 _TFC6Medico11NewAdressVC13chooseAddressfT_T_ + 259
    11  myApp                              0x0000000106b11449 _TFC6Medico11NewAdressVC11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 985
    12  myApp                              0x0000000106b12152 _TToFC6Medico11NewAdressVC11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000109c11a3d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000109c18062 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000109c431d3 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1290
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000109c53e48 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 697
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000109c54fdb -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000109e4bdd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000109b34ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109686bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010967a440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010967a2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109608318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    24  QuartzCore                          0x00000001096353ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    25  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109635d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c102267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c1021d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0e6f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0e6884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ec0ea6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    31  UIKit                               0x0000000109a6fc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    32  myApp                              0x0000000106ba8c2f main + 111
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d1a468d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't know why it is crashing, because it start crashing yesterday. But on device all ok

Here is my code, but even if I put this callback empty it still crashing. I don't know what to do

let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

```
placePicker.pickPlace(callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: Error?) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
        print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    guard let place = place else {
        print("No place selected")
        return
    }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 18)
    self.mapView.camera = camera
    self.marker.position = place.coordinate
    self.marker.map = self.mapView
    self.marker.appearAnimation = .pop

    print("#Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
    if let addr = place.formattedAddress {
        self.addressString = addr
    }

    self.updateAddressCell(place)
    self.lastSelectedPlace = place

    self.saveChangesButton.isHidden = false

})
```

Comment: You got it fixed?

Comment: I receive the same crash on devices as well. They seem to start randomly and don't stop. Install the app, use it for a while and then the crashes appear. Only app reinstall helps. No app killing/restarting or device restarting helps.

Comment: If you are still seeing an issue please look for a relevant report on the issue tracker and if you can't find one report a new issue via: http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188842&template=788908